# Connecting three classes in Pyqt4

Tags: python, class, pyqt

I want to connect classes A, B and C so that When I push a button in class B, I get to open class C (which is hidden) inside of class A.

I tried something like this:

```
class A(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__()

    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab)      #I've got this from QDesigner


    self.c = C()
    self.c.hide()            #I want to open it when i push a button

    self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
    self.splitter.addWidget(self.c)
    self.splitter.addWidget(anotherWidgets)

    self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.layout.addWidget(self.splitter)
    self.tab.setLayout(self.layout)
class B(QMainWindow):             #This is a matplotlib figure and i added 
                                  #a button in the toolbar of matplotlib
  def__init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here

  def openC(self):
    self.button = QPushButton("Open")
    self.connect(self.button, SIGNAL("clicked()", self.openWindow)

  def openWindow(self):
    a =  A()
    a.c.show()

class C(QDialog):
  pass            #This is QDialog that is shown when i click in the button
                  #of the toolbar in the matplotlib figure
```

So, i want to open/show the QDialog (class C) by clicking a button created in class B (the matplotlib figure), and that i need to be shown in class A (which is the Main window). After this i can create another button to close/hide it.

How can I accomplish this? Hope you can help me

Comment: why do you hide c when it's not even shown yet?

Comment: Because it is a Matplotlib figure that i want to see every time i press the button.

Comment: change `self.c = class c()` to `self.c = c()`

Comment: That was a typo. Sorry, i`ve already edited it.

Comment: i still don't get you, do you want to see seven different instances (windows) when you click the button?, if so there is no need to hide the window in A

Comment: I explained it better now. Hope this helps to understand what i need. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hi @PabloFlores , I see that this question has not been answered yet. It dates back to Feb 25. Did you solve the problem? If not, then I would be happy to investigate it for you.
Kind greetings,

Comment: Hi, not it was not. I had to change the code to do it in another way.
I'll be be very grateful if you can help me.